# We are 5, former 8 from the 70s.

Tags: riddle, music

One of us has the voice

One of us has the Katy

The first went from the World to the Country

We ran with McDaniels

And we've been heroes

Some say we're crazy

For playing with the toys in the attic

But there's not a sweeter emotion

than lovin' in an elevator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> Aerosmith

We are 5, former 8 from the 70s.

> There's 5 current members, with three additional past members (totalling 8) and they're from the 70s.

One of us has the voice

> Steven Tyler is the singer of the group and also a judge on American Idol (which is not quite The Voice).

One of us has the Katy

> Joe Perry shares a last name with Katy Perry (since she changed her name from Katy Hudson), though they are not related.

The first went from the World to the Country

> They are a world-famous rock band and now Steven Tyler has released some country songs (though not with Aerosmith).

We ran with McDaniels

> Run DMC (with Darryl McDaniels as a member) rerecorded Walk This Way with Aerosmith.

And we've been heroes

> They have a Guitar Hero dedicated to them.

Some say we're crazy
For playing with the toys in the attic
But there's not a sweeter emotion
than lovin' in an elevator

> Crazy, Toys in the Attic, Sweet Emotion, and Love in an Elevator are all Aerosmith songs.

Comment: I suppose it was too easy, good job nevertheless =)

Comment: It was the last line that gave it away.